# Fast checking Matrix multiplication in mod 10

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, matrices, modular-arithmetic

I recently faced this problem in a programming contest: Given 3 square matrices N x N of size N up to 1000. All elements in 3 matrices are from 0 to 9. Check if matrix A x B equals to C, mod 10. In other words, return the result of expression `(A x B) mod 10 == C`.

For example:

$\qquad A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 5 & 8 \\ 
 1 & 4 & 9 \\ 
 2 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 6 \\ 
 3 & 7 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\qquad 
C = \begin{bmatrix}
 9 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
 8 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$

return: TRUE

If

$\qquad C = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
 8 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$

return: FALSE, since the element C(1, 1) must be 9.

Time limit is 1s, pretty strict. Please gives me some idea how to solve the problem efficiently; is it possible time $O(N^2)$?

Comment: Note that a time limit in seconds and $O(\dots)$ are incomparable measures, with the answers probably wildly different. What is your priority? (For example, a time limit for any fixed $N$ can be realised by employing recursive matrix multiplication algorithms and storing all (preprocessed) products up to a certain size.)

Comment: My first choice would be a solution which runs in time limit :)

Comment: Have you considered [Freivalds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm)? It's probabilistic but will give the right answer with probability at least $1-2^{-k}$ in time $O(kn^2)$. I'm not sure how good it is, in practice.

Comment: Adding to @DavidRicherby's comment: for $k \approx 10$ (or so) the probability of the algorithm messing up is smaller than the probability of the processor flipping a bit accidentally.

Comment: @Raphael $k=10$ gives an error rate of about one in a thousand. That's a lot higher than the probability of the CPU randomly flipping a bit. But, yes, you don't need a very big $k$ to get reliability that's indistinguishable from perfect.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Heh, I was a bit optimistic there, not really thinking about the number. My bad. :> What do you think? IIRC, $2^{100}$ is about the number of atoms in the universe, so I guess somewhere in between?

Comment: @Raphael I don't know so I [asked a question about it](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29091/9550)!

Comment: (I should add that the bound mentioned by @DavidRicherby holds if *and only if* you have a proper source of (pseudo) random numbers. If not, arbitrarily bad stuff can happen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Accepted by using Freivald's algorithm as suggested by @David Richerby. Thank you very much !

I have not tested the brute-force solution using Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm yet. Will report in a couple of days, by the way I think it might not get Accepted but possibly will gain a fairly amount of points.

For those who want to check your implementation, submit your code on http://vn.spoj.com/problems/VMATRIX/. The problem statement is in Vietnamese, so here is the short description of input format:

> - First line is number of testcase (the example gives 2 testcases)
> - For each testcase:
> - the first line is size of 3 matrices, N. In 20% testcase N <= 100.
> - next N * N lines: matrix A
> - next N * N lines: matrix B
> - next N * N lines: matrix C

Output: YES or NO for the result.

Comment: As I commented below [mohaned's answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29087/9550), Coppersmith–Winograd isn't competitive for the sorts of matrices you're dealing with. For the sizes of matrices you're dealing with, the naive $O(n^3)$ algorithm with a few optimizations tends to be faster than any of the fancy, asymptotically faster algorithms.